# How can I parse the list of datetime strings with a format that would suit every value in the list?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing, python-dateutil

So the situation is this: I have a pandas dataframe with datetime index. This index, however, is in a string format, and I don't know which format is used, but I do know that it is the same one for every value. My obvious choice for parsing a datetime string without a known format would be to use a `parse` function from `dateutil.parser`. But there could be some ambiguities about some of the values, for example `"2020-01-02"` could be both February 1st or January 2nd, so it could be either in a `%Y-%m-%d` format or in a `%Y-%d-%m` format. But in the same dataframe I also have a value of `"2020-01-30"` which can only be parsed with `%Y-%m-%d` format. So at that point I know that all of the values in this dataframe are actually in this particular format and I want to parse all of them the same.

The problem is, `dateutil` function can only be applied to single values, and not to lists. As far as I understand, while `dateutil.parser.parse` is capable of parsing myriads of datetime formats, it cannot give you back information about what format it used, so I cannot use the parsing information from one value (that can only be parsed in 1 way) and use it for the other (that can be parsed 2 or more ways)

My second idea was to write my own function that would use as many known datetime formats as possible and try to apply them to all values in the dataframe index one by one. At this point that monster was born:

```
def parse_df_index(df):    
    possible_datetime_formats = [
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
            '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S',
            '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M',
            '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',
            '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',
            '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
            '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
            ...
        ]
    for date_format in possible_datetime_formats:
        try:
            index = [dt.datetime.strptime(t, date_format) for t in df.index]
        except:
            pass
    df.index = index
    return df
```

This approach, while dependent on my datetime format research (which didn't even scratch the surface of what dateutil function can do), has been broken by the string `'2019-07-29 00:00:00+04:00'`, produced by none other than pandas itself. No matter how I tried, I couldnt find a way to use `strptime` to parse this timezone format.

At that point I'm lost. I'm sure it's not such a rare situation I'm in, so someone has probably solved it? I hope...

Comment: This looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247063/pandas-datetimes-with-different-formats-in-the-same-column).  Does this solve the problem?

Comment: It's the opposite question. This guy has multiple datetime formats in one column, and he knows what are the formats. I only have one, but it is unknown

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `pd.to_datetime()`?  This allows the function to utilize the `infer_datetime_format` argument conveniently.

```
df['date_parsed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['raw_date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

If some specific lines have a very particular format which might cause errors, you can also use the `errors` argument.

Comment: This approach also does not use a single string format for every value. Example:

`df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': ['01-02-2020', '15-02-2020']
})
`


`pd.to_datetime(df.datetime, infer_datetime_format=True)` gives this result: 

0   2020-01-02
1   2020-02-15

It used %m-%d-%Y format for the first value and %d-%m-%Y for the second